# A casino owner is concerned based on past experience that his dice show 6 too often

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, hypothesis-testing

Currently I am trying to understand hypothesis testing, but I have a problem with the following question:

```
A casino owner is concerned based on past experience that his dice show
6 too often. He makes his employees roll a die 18,000 times and they observe
3,123 sixes. Is the die biased?
```

So from this text I used the following test:
$$ h0 := p = \frac{1}{6} = unbiased $$
$$ h1 := p \ne \frac{1}{6} = biased $$
The problem is that I don't how to calculate it. First I tried this formula:
$$ \frac{\hat x - \mu}{SE} $$
$$ SE= \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $$

$$ \frac{3123-3000}{\frac{\sqrt{18000\cdot\frac{3123}{18000}\cdot\frac{14874}{18000}}}{\sqrt{18000}}} = 0.018478$$

Also I tried the following formula:

$$ \frac{\frac{3123}{18000} - \frac{3000}{18000}}{\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6}}{18000}}} =2.46$$
And if I look at the z value. It is different than the answer of my textbook.

Did I use the wrong formula?

According to the book, the answer is .0081

Comment: You need to look up how dice work. $p=1/2$ is the null hypothesis???

Comment: Sorry, I looked for p=1/6. thx for noticing. I edited it.

Comment: What $z$ score do you get?

Comment: From the Z table I got .4931. And because I need to reject if is not eqeal 1/2, I think it is a two sized sample. So I did this: $$ .4931 * 2=.9862 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this test what we're interesting in is the distribution of our test statistic *when the null hypothesis is true*, which is binomial$(n = 18,000, p = 1/6)$.  So the standard error need not be estimated from the data, it's known to be exactly $\sqrt{18,000 \times 1/6 \times 5/6}$, and this should be the value you use in your calculation.  More importantly, the formula you use for the standard error is for the *proportion of sixes*, but you're apparently using the total number as a test statistic, so your standard error is off by a fairly large factor.

Also, the number of sixes go from being 3,123 in the problem to 3,126 in your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your formula, but I still can't get the correct answer.

Comment: I did the calculation in R and using a normal approximation I got $z = 2.46$ and a $p$-value of approximately 0.014.  Another guess is they might be calculating an exact $p$-value based on the binomial distribution, but I kind of doubt it.

Comment: Ah, I got the same answer as you.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach the problem might be to calculate the standard score as the number of standard deviations for the observation from the expected value:

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{18000\times\frac{1}{6}\times(1 - \frac{1}{6})} = 50\\
z = \frac{3123-\frac{18000}{6}}{50} = 2.46
$$

If my understanding is correct, **2.46** is a high standard score which has less than 1% probability of happening given a normal distribution so it is likely that the die is biased.

Another way to approach the problem might be to check whether the expected probability of **1/6** falls within the probability of the observation with a confidence level of 95% (Z = **1.9599**):

$$
s_p = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{6}\times(1 - \frac{1}{6})}{18000}} = \frac{1}{360}\\
E = Z\times s_p = \frac{1.9599}{360} = 0.0054\\
p = \frac{3123}{18000} = \frac{347}{2000} = 0.1735\\
0.1682 = p - E < r < p + E = 0.1789
$$

Again, if my understanding is correct, **1/6** does not fall within the range of the observation so it still seems likely that the die is biased.

As for the **0.0081** answer in your book, I don't understand how that can be the answer to a yes/no question. I might point out that this number happens to be the reciprocal of the difference between your observation and the expected value:

$$
\frac{1}{3123-\frac{18000}{6}} = 0.0081
$$

However, I don't understand how that relates to your problem. Please keep us posted on your progress!

Comment: I'm not sure what calculator you're using, but $\sqrt{18000 \times 1/5 \times 5/6} \cong 54.77$, and $(3123 - 3000) / 50 = 2.46$, not $4.92$.

Comment: For the first part, you'll get the same result if you use **1/6** instead of **1/5**. For the second part, you're right and **2.46** certainly seems more likely as a standard score. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I accepted the other answer, because the formula he used is the one I was looking for.